# Running my own camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm a beginner to Java and Android, and I have a problem with launching a camera. Precisely I need a small camera preview that would be under my control. (I want to put a sight in the middle of it). I tried to paste this to my project:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html
But there are loads of errors, after my naive 'fixing', program crashes, before starting anything.. 
I tried searching google for quite a long time, unsuccessfully.
Is somebody in posession of something that would just work without problems? A project would be nice :)

Thanks in advance
Bye

Comment: Try this one: http://www.tomgibara.com/android/camera-source Or this one: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html Or here: http://p2p.wrox.com/book-professional-android-application-development-isbn-978-0-470-34471-2/72528-article-using-android-camera.html

Comment: If you could rephrase the question, that would be a great help. Right now, it's hard to figure out what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

in your onCreate method, provide the below lines,

```
String  imgName = getImageName();

    startCamera(imgName);
```

And below your onCreate, provide these methods. your camera is ready.

```
   private void startCamera(String ImageName) {


    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

    cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(new File(ImageName)));

    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PICTURE_WITH_CAMERA);
}

private String getImageName() {
    String imgname = "";
    String imgpath = "";
        String strDirectory="/sdcard";
    try {
        imgname = String.format("%d.mp4", System.currentTimeMillis());

        imgpath = strDirectoy + "/" + imgname;

        File file = new File(strDirectoy);
        boolean exists = file.exists();
        if (!exists) {
            boolean success = (new File(strDirectoy)).mkdir();
            if (success)
                Log.e("Directory Creation", "Directory: " + strDirectoy
                        + " created");
            else
                Log.e("Directory Creation", "Error in Create Directory");
        }

        Log.i("Imagename : ", imgpath);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("fileException", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return imgpath;
}
```

Comment: Here you use a constant TAKE_PICTURE_WITH_CAMERA. My eclipse couldn't fix it. Should I define it myself? What should be the value?

Comment: Sorry, here it is.  int TAKE_PICTURE_WITH_CAMERA = 0;